# Deploy W10 on HP ProDesk 600 G2

Tags: sccm

I'm deploying windows 10 via SCCM on new computer it loads into PXE then reboot.. When I try `ipconfig` I'm not getting ip so I though it will be problem with `NIC`.. so I tried to load all available drivers for this desktop and still not working.. I'm out of ideas..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> > "so I tried to load all available drivers for this desktop and still not working.. "

Did you mean that you add all drivers of this model into the boot image which associated with the OSD task sequence? If so, that is not recommended by MS. You should only import the actually required NIC drivers or storage drivers into the boot images(both x86 and x64).

Another important point here is you should add the NIC drivers match the boot image version instead of the OS version you are trying to deploy. For example, add NIC drivers for win10 to the boot image 10.x.xxxxx (which is from the ADK 10 RTM or later).